# I create a main page and all its code means header, footer etc i distribute in different pages

Tags: laravel, master-pages, extends

I create a main page and all its  code means header, footer etc i distribute in different pages and i  linked all pages with main page through  include method...main page work properly except one code given below

main pages

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   @include('partails._header')
 <body>
<!-- <  navbar-->
    @include('partails._navbar')
<!-- end navbar -->
<div class="container">
    @include('partails._body')


</div>
  <hr>
    @include('partails._footer')
    @include('partails._script')
  </body>
</html>
```

folder name partials and _body i want to include in main page but not work

_body code is given

```
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="list-group">
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item">First item</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Second item</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    {{-- end 4 --}}
    <div class="col-md-8">
     @yield('content')
    </div>
   </div>
```

{{-- end row --}}

folder name partials and _body i want to include in main page but not work

_body code is given

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="list-group">
           <a href="#" class=enter code here"list-group-item">First item</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Third item</a>
         </div>
     </div>
    {{-- end 4 --}}
<div class="col-md-8">
    @yield('content') 
</div>
```

{{-- end row --}}

Comment: @yield('content') is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

If your body.blade.php is located in partials folder just include this way

```
@include('partials.body')
```

By saying yield('content') not working properly, what do you mean? How are you passing other view(blade) to the main page via content?